# Sympy: How to get a list of summands of one equation/expression

Tags: expression, sympy, addition

I am seeking for a method to extract the high level summands of an expression, preferably in a kind of list. What I mean is the following:

Consider the following expression:

```
a+ b*log(c+1)+d*e**(f+g)
```

What I mean by high level summands, are the summands like this:
`(a, b*log(c+1), d*e**(f+g))`

I do not want to get the summands of the logarithm (c+1) or (f+g) for example.

I saw that there is a description of the "advanced expression manipulation", but do not know how to solve my speficic problem.
Perhaps there is an already implemented function like summands(expr), which I could not find yet?

Best regards,
Johannes.

Comment: `expr.args` returns the top-level arguments of a sympy expression `expr`. See the [advaced expression manipulation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#args) for details

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all terms in an expression in Sympy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566132/how-to-find-all-terms-in-an-expression-in-sympy)